# Youtube Video Gallery not working properly - html css

Tags: html, css, responsive, gallery

I am making a portfolio website, and when the user clicks on the video tab it should have two embedded, responsive, youtube videos in the form of a gallery. I have tried achieving this, but for some odd reason, the second video is very tiny.

I haven't made the size for the second one any different, so I am pretty stumped on how to fix this. (The second video should be the same size as the first one)

Here's my code:

```css
.embed-container-1{
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 ratio */
     height: 0;
}

.embed-container-2{
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 ratio */
     height: 0;
}

.embed-container-1 iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.embed-container-2 iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-web">
          <div class='embed-container-1'><iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/jNQXAC9IVRw' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 portfolio-item filter-web">
          <div class='embed-container-2'><iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/jNQXAC9IVRw' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

Appreciate any help,
Thanks!

P.S: portfolio-item filter-web is how the videos go to the video section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, I just forgot to close the div tag for the "portfolio-item filter-web". So sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing more of your code would be helpful to see where the issue is coming from. Are they both in the same column? If so, either put them in separate columns or use flexbox to display them proportionally or set the width of each container to 50%.